# def - это оператор? Почему def get_now(now=time.time()) одно и то же значение для now выдает

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
def get_now(now=time.time()):
    return now
```

Если в итерпретаторе вызывать несколько раз  `get_now()`, то оно все время выдает одно и то же значение. По видимому, это время когда `def` выполнился в первый раз. Я правильно понимаю?
Получается - что `def`  это просто оператор??
Тогда что он делает?

Comment: `def` - это "определение", ключевое слово означающее начало определения функции

Comment: связанный вопрос: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

> Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is
>   defined, not each time the function is called

то есть

> Питоновские параметры "по умолчанию" вычисляются один раз, во время
>   определения функции, а не каждый раз, когда функция вызывается.

Answer (score 2):

`def` это ключевое слово, которое задаёт определение функции. Функции являются объектами в Питоне. `def get_now(now=time.time()): return now` можно рассматривать как:

```
f = time.time()
get_now = Function(name='get_now', 
                   args=Args(names=['now'], defaults=(f,)),
                   code=<block>)
```

то есть значение по умолчанию вычисляется сразу, один раз и не пересчитывается. По этой причине, в общем случае не стоит изменяемые объекты использовать в качестве аргументов по умолчанию.

Это часто задаваемый вопрос: [Why are default values shared between objects?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects)

Если вы хотите, чтобы текущее время возвращалось:

```
get_now = time.time
```